# Why are there no spaces in Hangul-Words (XeLaTeX - xeCJK)

Tags: spacing, xetex

This is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Batang}

\begin{document}
        나는 남자를 이다
\end{document}
```

As you see, there are spaces between the Korean words. I compiled with XeLaTeX => PDF with XeTeX Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (MiKTeX 2.9) in TeXnicCenter. However there are no spaces in the outputfile. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to enable the `CJKspace` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[CJKspace]{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{GungSeo} % a font with Hangul characters I have

\begin{document}

나는 남자를 이다

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You for your fast reply! I searched for ages.. It's working!

Comment: @Felix Consider that I can't read Chinese, Japanese or Korean; but I searched for `space` in the documentation, found the option and tried it. `:)`

Comment: I'll definitely do this next time too!

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I find that leaving some spaces between Chinese words actually can make the text more readable, even though it is not the standard practice for Chinese texts.